# How to combine the initial state of a row with the latest state in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I need to get the initial state as well as the latest state from a MySQL database. This is over two tables:

`customer`

| id | name | surname | dob | email | telephone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Steve | Bobbly | 01-01-1970 | uvw@xyz.com | 0123456789 |
| 15 | James | Bond | 01-01-1950 | 007@bond.com | 0101010999 |

`audit_log`

| id | entity_id | property | old_value | new_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | name | John | Steve |
| 2 | 10 | email | abc@def.com | uvw@xyz.com |
| 3 | 10 | telephone |  | 0123456789 |

What I expect is output like this:

| id | name | surname | dob | email | telephone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | Steve | Bobbly | 01-01-1970 | uvw@xyz.com | 0123456789 |
| 10_1 | John | Bobbly | 01-01-1970 | abc@def.com |  |
| 15 | James | Bond | 01-01-1950 | 007@bond.com | 0101010999 |

I initially had a PHP script that runs through all the `customer` rows, and then matches them to the `audit_log` rows and generate output from there, but the speed is EXTREMELY slow and resource intensive.

Would something like this be possible directly in MySQL, and how would I do it?

### EDIT

I've added additional rows to the `customer` and the output tables. The output table needs to contain all rows in `customer`, as well as a copy of the initial row, built from `audit_log`.

Comment: 1) Is there only one update per each `entity_id` and `property` pairs at most ?
2) Can you please tag the version of the DBMS?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan No, there could be multiple updates of each `entity_id` and `property`. MySQL version is 5.6.51

Comment: I would consider upgrading your MySQL version, you're limited to what you can do for this using 5.6.

Comment: Are the updates rare?  new_value and old_value seem swapped??  Are you building the output only for a singe user?  Or for all users at the same time?

Comment: Updates can occur every day. This script will run only when someone requests the data. All users at the same time, that's what makes PHP not viable in this case.

Comment: You have tagged MySQL 5.6 - just to check, is an upgrade to 8 out of the question?

Comment: Let me rephrase my question...  If the typical person has no updates, then we might be able to run two different queries -- one to handle non-updated people (very fast and efficient), plus another, more complex, query for those with changes.

Comment: So, "10_1" is the "original" state?  Is it possible that, say, the telephone is changed twice?  If so, do we skip the intermediate value?

Comment: @SteveChambers: Unfortunately at the moment, yes. Trust me, if I could, I'd update to mysql 8 today. But we are working to get the project into a state where we can leverage newer tech. Don't ask me the symfony version, you won't stop laughing.

Comment: @RickJames: Re. the 10_1 question. Yes. If the phone number is changed twice, I do not care about the middle number. I just want what it was at the start, and what it is currently.

Because of the way this query is used, it needs to be 1 query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
SET @rn=0;
SET @cust=null;
SET @pr=null;

SELECT id, name, surname, dob, email, telephone
FROM customer 
  UNION ALL
(
  SELECT CONCAT(T.id, '_', D.rownum) id,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE D.property WHEN 'name' THEN D.old_value END), MAX(T.name)) name,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE D.property WHEN 'surname' THEN D.old_value END), MAX(T.surname)) surname,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE D.property WHEN 'dob' THEN D.old_value END), MAX(T.dob)) dob,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE D.property WHEN 'email' THEN D.old_value END), MAX(T.email)) email,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE D.property WHEN 'telephone' THEN D.old_value END), MAX(T.telephone)) telephone
  FROM customer T
  JOIN 
  (
    SELECT id, entity_id, property, old_value, new_value, 
    IF(@cust <> entity_id OR @pr <> property, @rn:=1, @rn:=@rn+1) rownum,
    @cust:=entity_id, @pr:=property
    FROM audit_log 
    ORDER BY entity_id, property, id
  ) D
  ON T.ID = D.entity_id
  WHERE D.rownum=1
  GROUP BY T.id, D.rownum
)
ORDER BY id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/beRZDA1b).

This query simulates `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY entity_id, property ORDER BY id)` for the audit_log table to get the initial value for each customer/ property (where rownum = 1) .

The `COALESCE` is used to get the value of a property from the customers table, if this property is not changed, i.e. the name is changed but the email is not, then for email get the lastest value (in this case the latest=initial, which is T.email in this query).

Answer (score 0):

Considering there's at most one update per each **`entity`**-**`property`** pairs per each **`entity_id`** value, you can use this SQL Select statement

```
SELECT a.entity_id, a.name, c.surname, c.dob, a.email, a.telephone
  FROM customer AS c
 CROSS JOIN ( SELECT entity_id, 
                     MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'name' THEN new_value END) AS name,
                     MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'email' THEN new_value END) AS email,
                     MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'telephone' THEN new_value END) AS telephone
                FROM audit_log 
               GROUP BY entity_id
               UNION ALL
              SELECT CONCAT(entity_id,'_1'), 
                     MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'name' THEN old_value END) AS name,
                     MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'email' THEN old_value END) AS email,
                     MAX(CASE WHEN property = 'telephone' THEN old_value END) AS telephone
                FROM audit_log 
               GROUP BY entity_id ) AS a
  WHERE a.entity_id = c.id
```

where changing `properties` which take place in **audit_log** table with `old` vs. `new` values are unpivoted, and the others(non-changing ones) taken from `customer` table

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Z7I_tMtI)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the script. There's an issue with this script, though. If there's a row in `customer` that does not have any records in `audit_log` it just duplicates the `UNION`ed rows.

Comment: Right @Bird87ZA , I missed the matching condition `WHERE a.entity_id = c.id`, just added

Comment: Hi @BarbarosÖzhan, firstly, thanks for your script. I've added additional rows to the initial question, as I don't think my question was clear enough with the data I posted. I've tried adapting your script to get it to work, but I can't get it right.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question! :-) Here is one way if you don't mind some repetition:

```
SELECT *
FROM customer
UNION ALL
SELECT
  CONCAT(id, '_1') AS id,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT old_value
     FROM audit_log
     WHERE id = (
       SELECT MIN(id)
       FROM audit_log WHERE entity_id = c.id AND property = 'name')
    ),
    c.name)
  AS name,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT old_value
     FROM audit_log
     WHERE id = (
       SELECT MIN(id)
       FROM audit_log WHERE entity_id = c.id AND property = 'surname')
    ),
    c.surname)
  AS surname,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT old_value
     FROM audit_log
     WHERE id = (
       SELECT MIN(id)
       FROM audit_log WHERE entity_id = c.id AND property = 'dob')
    ),
    c.dob)
  AS dob,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT old_value
     FROM audit_log
     WHERE id = (
       SELECT MIN(id)
       FROM audit_log WHERE entity_id = c.id AND property = 'email')
    ),
    c.email)
  AS email,
  COALESCE(
    (SELECT old_value
     FROM audit_log
     WHERE id = (
       SELECT MIN(id)
       FROM audit_log WHERE entity_id = c.id AND property = 'telephone')
    ),
    c.telephone)
  AS telephone
FROM customer c
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM audit_log WHERE entity_id = c.id)
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/ylu42qd9)** (shamelessly borrowing from the one set up by Barbaros Özhan)

**Note:** The above will include the `_1` entries whenever there are audit entries. But just the presence of audit entries doesn't guarantee anything has changed - e.g. if the surname was changed from "Smith" to "Jones" and then back to "Smith". If this is important to you I may be able to modify it, at the expense of more complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a tough programming task is best handled by stepping back and rethinking the framework.

I would re-think the schema design.  Instead of this complex query, I would have 3 tables, making the query 'trivial':

- `Original` -- The values when the person is first put into the database.
- `Audit` -- The blow-by-blow -- a historical record of all the changes.  (Optionally like you have now.  Or possibly a copy of the `Current` row when the change occurred.)
- `Current` - The latest values.

Then the query is essentially a `UNION` of `Original` and `Audit`.